# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to seed database code is as follow

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
         Model::unguard();
         //DB::table('artists');
       // factory(App\Artist::class, 50)->create();

        factory(App\Artist::class, 10)
           ->create()
           ->each(function($u) {
                $u->album()->save(factory(App\Album::class)->make());
            });

          Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please post your App\Artist file contents please

Comment: And the Album class too